# Why is sp_helpdb is giving strange results?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

`sp_helpdb` is giving me wrong results for log size/free:

```
device_fragments               size          usage                created                   free kbytes      
------------------------------ ------------- -------------------- ------------------------- ---------------- 
data_device2                       1024.0 MB data only            Nov  5 2011  5:24AM                    238 
log_device1                         640.0 MB log only             Nov  5 2011  5:24AM       not applicable   
data_device1                       2048.0 MB data only            Nov  5 2011  5:24AM                 980560 
data_device1                       1024.0 MB data only            Nov  5 2011  9:41AM                1044480 
log_device1                        1024.0 MB log only             Nov  5 2011  9:41AM       not applicable   



-------------------------------------------------------------- 
log only free kbytes = 1723580
```

---

Summing log only data size, it gives 1024+640 = 1664

But log free in mb is 1723580/1024 = 1 683.18359

---

**How is it possible to have more free log space than the total size?**

> Sybase version:
>  Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3/EBF 16736
>   ESD#2/P/Sun_svr4/OS 5.8/ase1503/2707/64-bit/FBO/Sun Jul 26 10:29:50
>   2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a guess but any chance these are allocated values instead of used values? Maybe your log was bigger than it was cleaned and Sybase kept the apace allocated for it. I know that SQL Server does this when increasing the DB file sizes so just a guess...

Comment: I'll accept your answer as the correct one. If I discover anything else I'll answer it as well :)